# creating Physic body in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am creating the physical body in box2d as below , this si my code

```
 b2BodyDef carBodyDef;
carBodyDef.position.Set(x/PTM_RATIO,y/PTM_RATIO);
carBodyDef.type=b2_dynamicBody;    b2Body* carBody=physicsWorld->CreateBody(&carBodyDef);

b2CircleShape carShape;
carShape.m_radius=rad/40.0f;


b2FixtureDef carFixture;
carFixture.shape=&carShape;
carFixture.density = 1.0f;
carFixture.friction = 0.0f;

carBody->CreateFixture(&carFixture);

return carBody ;
```

When am running the app, its getting crash , 
with the below erro
***Assertion failed: (IsLocked() == false), function CreateBody,***in box2d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are creating your body during execution of `Step()` function of `b2World`. You can't create new bodies while this function is executing