# Cocos2d box2d Assertion Failed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, box2d

This is my first box2d game and I am currently following one of Ray Wenderlich collision detection tutorials, however in this code snippet below, I get an error saying "Assertion failed: (IsLocked() == false), function CreateBody". Ive researched the error and know the problem but do not have a solution. Any one have a solution?

```
- (void)addBoxBodyForSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite {
b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
spriteBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
spriteBodyDef.position.Set(sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
spriteBodyDef.userData = sprite;
b2Body *spriteBody = _world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);
b2PolygonShape spriteShape;
```

Comment: If you already know the problem, it would help if you mentioned it here.

Comment: Its explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428367/creating-physic-body-in-cocos2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428367/creating-physic-body-in-cocos2d) you can't create bodies during `Step` function is executing. You have to store the information required to create the body somewhere and use it later (after `Step` exits) to create the body